# What does Gray Matter specialize in?

Tags: breaking-bad

It's often mentioned but it never explains what kind of research Walt's old company Gray Matter actually does in [*Breaking Bad*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the Scientific America on Walt's wall, Gray Matter made breakthroughs in Molecular Switches. *

Have a read [here](https://weakinteractions.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/the-science-of-breaking-bad-gray-matter/) for a good overview of science.  And Gray Matter.  A synopsis:

> From the text on the Scientific American cover and article, Gray
>   Matter Technologies has been making significant advances in the field
>   of molecular switches. Simply put, a molecular switch is a lot like a
>   mechanical switch – it has two (sometimes more) states, analogous to
>   on and off, and will change state when the environment is changed.

*shamelessly stolen from cde's comment on my own answer [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47125/does-producing-blue-meth-make-walter-a-chemistry-genius/47126#47126).

Comment: Never knew this! This is awesome, great find.

Comment: Found this "Elliott Schwartz is Walter White's old college science partner and co-owner of Gray Matter Technologies, a successful **pharmaceutical** company co-founded by Walter. Gretchen Schwartz, a former romantic interest of Walt, is Elliott's partner in the business and is his wife." on Breaking Bad wiki.

Answer (score 3):

**Research, but beyond that it's not explained in the show**

We know that in 2008 the company was nominated for a Nobel Prize, as it's mentioned in [*"...and the Bag's in the River"*](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/...and_the_Bag%27s_in_the_River). We also know it has a net worth of $2.16 billion dollars (from [Buyout)](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Buyout).

But it's actual purpose is unknown and not explored in the series.